# How to check Nodemailer's outgoing mail log?

Tags: nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer in my Ubuntu 20.04 environment with NodeJS and a React app. I use Nodemail for account verification and password reset tokens and everything works (for me). A customer tells me he doesn't receive an account verification email. When I create account I do get the mail, so something is going on (the customer says he's checked his spam as well). So I'm wondering if Nodemailer keeps a log (or can keep a log) of all outgoing email.

Comment: Why don't you check on whichever SMTP server you're connecting it to?

Comment: Because I was hoping Nodemailer would just store a record of send emails. Checking SMTP servers is new to me, so I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: You've told us nothing about your setup, maybe look at https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#debug-options but we don't even know if that's the transport you're using.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does that matter? All I'm asking is if Nodemailer keeps a record of send emails. `debug – if set to true, then logs SMTP traffic, otherwise logs only transaction events`. Thanks!